# RabbitMQ and EC2: Clusters can't join

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-cluster

I'm trying to create a RabbitMQ cluster.

The instances have been set up identically (They've been installed identically), they can resolve eachother's hostnames (Both with `dig`and `rabbitmqclt resolve_hostname`) and their cookie hash is the same.
I'm wondering whether or not there are more steps to setting up a RabbitMQ cluster when in EC2.

I'm running RabbitMQ 3.9.13 and Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you all in advance
-brej

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it should be sufficient, make sure to declare all these settings the config file of RabbitMQ, this way, each time it start, it will be able to reconnect to the cluster when needed.